# What does the JSLint error "Bad type." mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, types, type-conversion, jslint

When running a JavaScript file I'm developing through JSLint, I encountered this error:

```
Problem at line 387 character 68: Bad type.

  $iframe_contents.find('ul:last').append(OA_output['web' + x]);
```

I'm not sure what "bad type" means, nor can I find any more information about it through some searching. Acting on the theory that this line of code is doing some implicit type conversion that JSLint doesn't agree with, I changed the portion `['web' + x]` to just `['web']`, and that fixed the error. That lends support to my theory, since `x` is an integer, and the interpreter would need to perform type conversion to append it to the string `web`.

That leads me to my questions - is this indeed what the error "bad type" is referring to, and if so, is there something inherently wrong or dangerous about appending an integer to a string like this? What would be the proper way to write this line of code to avoid this error (ideally not to just appease JSLint)?

If needed, here's some quick background on what this line of code contains:

- `$iframe_contents` is a cached jQuery object: `$('iframe').contents()`.
- `.find()` and `.append()` are jQuery methods (http://api.jquery.com/find/ and http://api.jquery.com/append/, respectively).
- `OA_output` is an object, where `OA_output['web' + x]` contains a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's indeed what it is. JSLint will point out type inconsistency between a string and a number, even if JS interpreters can deal with it just fine. If you change it to `OA_output['web' + x.toString()]` you shouldn't have that problem.